# System call time measurement

Tags: ubuntu, system-calls, shared-library

I have implemented a  data copying loop using system functions write() and read() if -s command is used or C library functions if -l otherwise. I am trying to measure the time for the system call functions, but it does not work. Is it normal because the system calls are statically linked or not?
This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

static const char progname[] = "scat";

static int lcat(){
   int c;
   while (1) {
      if ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF){
         int n = putc(c, stdout);
         if (n == EOF){
            perror(progname);
            return -1;
         }
      }else{
         perror(progname);
         return -1;
      }
   }

   if (fflush(stdout) || ferror(stdout) || ferror(stdin)) {
      perror(progname);
      return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}

static int scat(){
   int c;
   ssize_t n;

   while (1){
      n = read(0, &c, 1);
      if (n < 0){
         perror(progname);
         return -1;
      }
      int m = write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
      if (m == -1 || m != 1){
         perror(progname);
         return -1;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int c, status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
   int (*vcat)() = lcat;

   while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "hls")) >= 0) {
      switch (c){
         case 'h':
            printf("Usage: %s [-h] [-l] [-s] files ... \n", progname);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
         case 's':
            vcat = scat;
            break;
         case 'l':
            vcat = lcat;
            break;
         default:
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }

   if (optind == argc) {
      if (vcat(NULL) < 0) {
         status = EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }else{
      for (; optind < argc; optind++) {
         if (vcat(argv[optind]) < 0) {
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
         }
      }
   }

   return status;
}
```

This is the command I am using:

```
time ./scat -s < some-large-file > /dev/null
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by 'does not work'. What output do you get? Does the program `scat` work as expected when you run it without `time`?

Comment: I apply the command time ./scat -s < some-large-file > /dev/null and I think it enters an infinite loop because when I do ./scat -l < some-large-file > /dev/null it shows me the real, user and sys time

Comment: I have just noticed that my program use an infinite number of system calls. That's why time does not work

Comment: Yes, you have reached the end of your file when `read` returns zero, but you don't check for this.